# Move tikz picture to other document lost transparency

Tags: tikz-pgf, overleaf

In Overleaf, if I draw a picture in a standalone document:

```
\documentclass[border=15pt, multi, tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,draw,text=white,fill=red, opacity=0.5] (c) at (0,0){Circle};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output image is correct:

[image]

If I move the code to another document, using an official class file from OUP:

```
\documentclass[oupdraft]{sysbio}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \resizebox{0.4\textwidth}{!}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[circle,draw,text=white,fill=red, opacity=0.5] (c) at (0,0){Circle};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The image lost transparancy:

[image]

The cls file can be downloaded [here](https://static.primary.prod.gcms.the-infra.com/static/site/sysbio/document/systematic-biology.zip?node=648cab459343d9342f1f&version=439387:1cc892dca83d586b69f5). An example Overleaf project can be found [here](https://www.overleaf.com/read/pdgdwjqhgnmw#7a2bda).

Is there anything that could cause the problem in the cls file?

Comment: the class redefines \enddocument and so breaks the hooks there. You could try `\let\orienddocument\enddocument
\documentclass[oupdraft]{sysbio}
\let\enddocument\orienddocument`.

Comment: Hi @UlrikeFischer, could you please elaborate more in detail? I am not quite good at latex

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I replaced the first line with your solution, it solved my problem

Comment: simply try my code (imho the worst that can happen is that you loose the history, but that can be reinserted manually.